# How to implement retry logic for making REST API call to get token every 5 mins in Golang

Tags: go, post, https, token

I have to make an API call to capture the response every 5 mins in Golang. How to implement retry logic for making REST API call to get response token every 5 mins in Golang?

```
res, err := http.Get("https://mydadisjoke.com/Acct?")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }   
    
    // defining a struct instance
    var KeyID Response
 
    // data in JSON format which
    // is to be decoded
    Data := []byte(`{
        "Key"                    :  "Key",
        "Account"                   :  "Account",
            }`)
 
    // decoding Response struct
    // from json format
    err := json.Unmarshal(Data, &KeyId)
 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
 
    // printing details of
    // decoded data
    fmt.Println("Struct is:", KeyId)
    fmt.Printf("Key is %s\n", KeyId.Key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make above code into one function, and add time control outside:

```
// define function
func doHttpCall() error {
    // above code

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// visit every 5min 
func main() {
    for {
        err := doHttpCall()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("API call failed:", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("API call success")
        }

        time.Sleep(5 * time.Minute)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`time.NewTicker(interval)`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#NewTicker):

> NewTicker returns a new Ticker containing a channel that will send the current time on the channel after each tick. The period of the ticks is specified by the duration argument. The ticker will adjust the time interval or drop ticks to make up for slow receivers. The duration d must be greater than zero; if not, NewTicker will panic. Stop the ticker to release associated resources.

---

Here it will call after 1 second for the first time and then 5 * time.Minute afterwards:

```
var interval = 1 * time.Second

func getPeriodically(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    t := time.NewTicker(interval)
    defer t.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            interval = 5 * time.Minute
            t.Reset(interval)
            k, err := demo(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                slog.Error("get", "error", err.Error())
                break
            }
            slog.Info("get", "key", k)

        case <-ctx.Done():
            slog.Info("getPeriodically: graceful shutdown completed")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

---

Complete example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "log/slog"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    slog.SetDefault(slog.New(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{AddSource: true})))
    slog.Info(Name, "Version", Version)
    slog.Info(Name, "GitCommit", GitCommit)
    slog.Info(Name, "runtime.Version", runtime.Version())

    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1) // Setup graceful shutdown
    // Docker and Kubernetes use the SIGTERM signal to gracefully shut down a container.
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    withServer := len(os.Args) == 1
    if withServer {
        wg.Add(1)
        go serve(ctx, &wg)
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go getPeriodically(ctx, &wg)

    // Wait for the termination signal
    slog.Info("Starting graceful shutdown", "Received termination signal", <-signals)
    if withServer {
        err := server.Shutdown(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            slog.Error("server", "error", err)
        }
    }

    cancel()

    wg.Wait()
    slog.Info("App: graceful shutdown completed")
}

var interval = 1 * time.Second

func getPeriodically(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    t := time.NewTicker(interval)
    defer t.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            interval = 5 * time.Minute
            t.Reset(interval)
            k, err := demo(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                slog.Error("get", "error", err.Error())
                break
            }
            slog.Info("get", "key", k)

        case <-ctx.Done():
            slog.Info("getPeriodically: graceful shutdown completed")
            return
        }
    }
}

func demo(ctx context.Context) (key string, err error) {
    get, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, address, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    res, err := client.Do(get)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    var KeyId *Response
    err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&KeyId)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    key = KeyId.Key
    return
}

type Response struct {
    Key string
}

func serve(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/Acct", home)

    server = &http.Server{
        Addr:         serverAddr,
        Handler:      mux,
        ReadTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    slog.Info("Server", "Addr", server.Addr)
    err := server.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        slog.Error("Server", "error", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    slog.Info("Server: graceful shutdown completed")
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    slog.Info("home", "ClientIP", clientIP(r))
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response{Status: 200, Key: "Key1234", Account: "Account1234"})
}

type response struct {
    Status  int
    Key     string
    Account string
}

func clientIP(r *http.Request) string {
    ip := r.Header.Get("X-Real-IP")
    if ip == "" {
        ip = r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")
        if ip == "" {
            ip = r.RemoteAddr
        }
    }
    return ip
}

var (
    address    = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Acct"
    serverAddr = ":8080"
    client     = http.Client{
        Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }
    server *http.Server

    Version, Name, GitCommit string
    // CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags="-s -X main.Version=$(Version) -X main.Name=$(Name) -X main.GitCommit=$(GIT_COMMIT)" -trimpath=true .
)
```